# how to sort dates by some particular order from the data [iphone]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

I have got some dates for some events and their ascending order from the database .

Now , I want want some buttons ..

in this structure ...

--######## Last Week #####----
--######## yesterday #####----

--######## today #####----

--######## tomorrow #####----
--######## Next Week #####----

Now when I press the respected buttons .. 
the events in that respected duration should be shown up ..

I mean all the data should be compared with today and all the data should be shorted by this order..

can anyone give me a idea or logic for this ?

Comment: What kind of front end do you use for your database? Is it Core Data or SQL, or something else? Are you looking for code that can automatically determine the dates for times like "last week" or are you looking for help with creating a predicate?

Comment: I am using SQLite and I dont want them to automatically determine , I want to sort them .. like today is 27 sept.. If i have the date which says I am from oct3 then it should be automatically added in block(array) of next week

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you need to calculate the start and end date for something like "next week" which is relative to any arbitrary date. Then, when the "next week" button is pushed, you get those two dates (start date and end date), then you can set up the sql statement with those dates as constraints, execute the query, and present the results. Does that descrbe it?  Which part do you need help with, specifically?

Comment: Yes , You are right .. I want to do the same .. but my problem is how ? 1) If I have the present date .. how will you decide the dates for yesterday, and last week and all that ... so I am not able to decide technically in iphone how to do this

Comment: adamsiton gives you a nice, robust way to do it in his answer below that won't break with daylight saving time issues. I use something similar myself, and I can say the method he shows is a good safe method. I recommend adding it as a category function to NSDate, like he does. It can be very handy to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to deal with dates is by using NSDateComponents.
for example, to get the date for tomorrow use:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comp = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
[comp setDay:1];
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDate *tomorrow = [cal dateByAddingComponents:comp toDate:today options:0];
```

So, what you need to do is:

1. Get the dates for all the relevant date categories
2. When you push a button, build a predicate to retrieve only the objects between the two dates. For example, getting all the objects in the "tomorrow" category:

   ```
   NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date > %@ AND date < %@", tomorrow, nextWeek];
   ```

You can use a small convenient method for getting the dates, by adding a category to NSDate with this method:

```
@implementation NSDate (Components)

-(NSDate *) dateByAddingCalendarUnit:(NSCalendarUnit)calendarUnit andCount:(NSInteger) count
{
    NSDateComponents *comp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    switch (calendarUnit) {
        case NSSecondCalendarUnit:
            [comp setSecond:count];
            break; 
        case NSMinuteCalendarUnit:
            [comp setMinute:count];
            break; 
        case NSHourCalendarUnit:
            [comp setHour:count];
            break; 
        case NSDayCalendarUnit:
            [comp setDay:count];
            break;  
        case NSWeekCalendarUnit:
            [comp setWeek:count];
            break; 
        case NSWeekdayCalendarUnit:
            [comp setWeekday:count];
            break;
        case NSWeekdayOrdinalCalendarUnit:
            [comp setWeekdayOrdinal:count];
            break; 
        case NSMonthCalendarUnit:
            [comp setMonth:count];
            break; 
        case NSYearCalendarUnit:
            [comp setYear:count];
            break; 
        case NSEraCalendarUnit:
            [comp setEra:count];
            break; 
        default:
            break;
    }

    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *newDate = [cal dateByAddingComponents:comp toDate:self options:0];
    [comp release];
    return newDate;
}

@end
```

And use this method like this:

```
NSDate *lastWeek = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingCalendarUnit:NSWeekCalendarUnit andCount:-1];
```